# Visual Studio Angular Template with Docker and docker-compose error

Tags: angular, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

would anyone know why I would get the following error:

```
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Users\porterc\Documents\Personal Projects\LostChapters\FrontEnds\LostChaptersSpa\lost-chapters-spa\lost-chapters-spa.esproj\lost-chapters-spa.exe" because it was not found.
```

In Visual Studio 2022 I added an Angular project to my already existing solution:

[image]

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine as builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.10-alpine
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/lost-chapters-spa /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here is my Docker-Compose file:

```
  lostchaptersspa:
   container_name: lost_chapters_spa
   image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}lostchaptersspa
   build: FrontEnds/LostChaptersSpa/lost-chapters-spa
   ports:
        - 4200:80
   networks:
        - lost_chapters_network
```

Why is it looking for this executable and is there a way for me to fix it?